# Multiprocessing update operation in PyMongo stuck after AutoReconnect error

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo, sleep

I'm trying to parallelize write operations to MongoDb by using Python's multiprocessing library. I have a list of files (about 500k), and a function that does some processing on a file and writes it to Mongo using `update_one`. The code runs for a while, but eventually, it just seems to hang after every process gets a AutoReconnect error (I only see this after I use Keyboard Interrupt).

The specific error message is `Exec error resulting in state DEAD :: caused by :: errmsg: "interrupted at shutdown".` I'd like each process to catch this error (if it occurs), sleep, then try again, but instead, every process runs into this error and all of them just hang there.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
def some_processing(filename):
    client = MongoClient('connection_string')
    collection = client['collection_name']
    done = False

    for i in range(5):
        if done is False:
            try:
                # some processing code
                collection.update_one({'field1':'value', ...})
                done = True
            except pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect as e:
                print(str(e))
                time.sleep(pow(2,x))

pool = Pool(processes=16)
results = pool.map(some_processing, ls_files, chunksize=1000)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: What is producing the error message you quoted (Exec error resulting in state DEAD :: caused by :: errmsg: "interrupted at shutdown") ? Why do you have keyboard interrupts?

Comment: I meant that I let the function run overnight, and I noticed it was still running the next morning so I manually did a Keyboard Interrupt in the Jupyter notebook that the function is running in, and then saw those error messages printed.

Comment: Any chance your updates are causing you to run out of disk space on the device which has the mongodb data directory?

Comment: Hmm @MichaelRuth I don't think that is the case because I have run this code serially before and it was able to complete without issues, it was just very slow.

Comment: Was your MongoDB deployment up and running when your application received these errors?

Comment: What do the mongodb logs look like?

Comment: @Oleg yea it was

Comment: @MichaelRuth I'm not sure how to access that, looking it up now. still new to MongoDb. Thought maybe I could solve the issue just by finding a mistake in my Python code but I'll take a look at the Mongo logs as you suggested.

Comment: @piedpiper The MongoDB logs are typically located in /var/log/mongodb on Linux and BSD systems. The log location may vary on Mac depending on whether mongod was installed through macports or homebrew. I've no clue where the logs are on Windows systems.

Comment: thanks @MichaelRuth. Checked the logs and saw some socket error. I also realized i could use insert_one instead of update_one for most of my files and now the code runs much faster